# Using html2pdf with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html2pdf

Hey guys I'm trying to generate a pdf file using html2pdf but I couldn't succeed to make it work because I get an unreadable content
so basically what I have is a simple php page that generate a pdf file

```php
$content = ob_get_clean();

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php');
try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', 0);
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $html2pdf->createIndex('Sommaire', 25, 12, false, true, 1);
    $html2pdf->Output('bookmark.pdf');
}
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
```

from the other side I have my service that he sends some data to it and get the file back something like this

```js
this.generatePDF = function (commande) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        //responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        url: 'vendor/modules/html2pdf/examples/bookmark.php',
        timeout: 15000,
        data: $.param({'data': commande}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'}
        //header :{"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=sample.pdf"}
     }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         debugger;
         deferred.resolve(response.data);
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
          deferred.resolve(response.statusText);
     });
     return deferred.promise;
};
```

for the last part which is the controller side when the user presse generate I call my service and bind data to it and then get the whole stuff back after success and write it into the content of a new window

```
var popup = $window.open('', 'TEST', 'width=500,height=900');

ServiceCommande.generatePDF($scope.commande).then(function (data) {
    popup.document.write(data);
});
```

the thing is a get some strange stuff instead of the pdf that I send 
[strange behavior pdf format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS9xE.jpg)

Thank you ^^

Comment: This is how a pdf looks like in text. It is not a readable format. You could - for testing purposes - take the strange stuff save it in a file with ending *.pdf* and try to open it. WHat do you want to do with your generated pdf? If you want to show it in a popup i guess you need to save it first as pdf and then you can load it into your html.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, Yeah this is exactly what I want it to do I'm already saving the file to a pdf format so instead of sending the whole pdf text I just need to send the current location for the file to open it is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)`. It has got a wide support for CSS elements.

Install it, and put the executable in system's environment PATH.
Create a  file `index.js`. Contents of this file will be:

```
//create page
var page= require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.paperSize = {
     format: 'A4',
     orientation: 'portrait'
}

//check for number of parameters
if (system.args.length < 3) {
   console.log('Usage: phantomjs index.js <web page URL> <ouptut path/filename>');
   phantom.exit();
}

page.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
     console.log("Status: " + status);
     if (status === "success") {
         page.render(system.args[2]);
     }
     else {
        console.log("Failed")
    }
phantom.exit();
});
```

Now fetch any webpage link, it will convert it into pdf, issuing commands as:

```
phantomjs index.js index.html index.pdf
```